# Where to place code to populate a UITextfield (title field) after a segue screen returns to main screen?

Tags: ios, swift, segue, nsuserdefaults, viewdidload

I am building a Swift - Single View app.  I’ve added a “segue" view to allow user to store a title line preference using NSUserDefaults.  When I return to the primary view the title line isn’t filled with the new title info from NSUserDefaults.  I’ve placed the code to populate the main screen title line in the viewDidLoad section noted below.  Strangely enough, if I go to the “segue" screen and back to main screen again without making changes then it shows up.  Where can I place code to get the title line stored in my preferences segue screen to show up when I go back to the main view?  Here is my code that works, but only after going back and forth from the seague twice.  Thanks for any help.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        let titlePref = defaults.objectForKey("usertitleLineKey")!
        titleLine.text = titlePref as! String
    }
```

Comment: Use `viewWillAppear`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` callback methods to refresh any content in your view when or just before it shows up. `viewDidLoad` will only be called once when the view is initialised on to memory.

Comment: That sounds like the correct way to get it done but I tried placing the override in my viewController.swift and it gives an error "Method does not override any method from its superclass".  I tried removing the word "override" and it runs error free but doesn't populate the titleLine.  Any suggestions.  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
override func viewWillAppear() {
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    let titlePref = defaults.objectForKey("usertitleLineKey")!
    titleLine.text = titlePref as! String
}
```

Comment: That sounds like the correct way to get it done but I tried placing the override in my viewController.swift and it gives an error "Method does not override any method from its superclass". I tried removing the word "override" and it runs error free but doesn't populate the titleLine. Any suggestions? thanks.

Comment: Okay, that fixed the problem.  I used the code snip above except added the line:  
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

Comment: Glad you got it working, please upvote if it answered your question